# Print All Subvector Combinations + Issue

Tags: c++, vector, combinatorics

I am attempting to create a tool that will make my life easier for setting up a list of configuration settings based on numerical addition to indicate which features should be enabled.  I am using a power of 2 list from 1 to 512 (1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512).

Manually going through and creating a list of which values will make which features enabled would be much too time consuming and so I am trying to do it programmatically then save the output into a file.  I am, however, running into problems finding a proper solution.

I have read just about every question from SO and other coding forums that have come up in Google on the topic and all of them address linear combinations.  This I am able to do and I have this example code that I altered and then built my tool on top of:

```
    #include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

// A is the array that contains the numbers
// comb is an array of size k that will hold all possible combinations
// n is the size of input array
// k is 1 less than the size of combination i.e. we want to find out 4C2 k =1
// current_k is the variable that makes us simulates k loops in a recursive function
void combinations(int A[], int comb[], int start, int n, int current_k, int k){
    int sum = 0;

    if (k < 0)
        return;

    // Base case just print all the numbers 1 at a time
    if (k == 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cout << A[i] << endl;
    }

    // current_k goes from 0 to k-1 and simulates a total of 
    // k iterations
    if (current_k < k){
        // if current_k = 0, and k = 3 (i.e. we need to find combinations of 4) 
        // then we need to leave out 3 numbers from the end because there are 3
        // more nested loops
        for (int i = start; i < n - (k - current_k); i++){
            // Store the number in the comb array and recursively call with the remaining sub-array
            comb[current_k] = A[i];
            // This will basically pass a sub array starting at index 'start' and going till n-1
            combinations(A, comb, i+1, n, current_k+1, k);
        }
    }

    else if (current_k == k){
        for (int i = start; i < n; i++){
            comb[current_k] = A[i];

            for (int j = 0; j <= k; j++){
                sum += comb[j];     
            }
            
            cout << sum << endl;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }

    else
        return;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the 'n' " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int *A = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        A[i] = i+1;

    int k;
    cout << "Enter 'k'" << endl;
    cin >> k;
    int *comb = new int[k];

    combinations(A, comb, 0, n, 0, k-1);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The only problem is that I also need the non-linear combinations.  Things like 1+64+256.  Will this also be able to pick up these combinations?  And I am also having an issue which I will explain after I post my code.  Here is the actual code I am using for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "mcl.h"

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

static vector<string> results;

// A is the array that contains the numbers
// comb is an array of size k that will hold all possible combinations
// n is the size of input array
// k is 1 less than the size of combination i.e. we want to find out 4C2 k =1
// current_k is the variable that makes us simulates k loops in a recursive function
void combinations(vector<mcl> A, vector<mcl> comb, int start, int n, int current_k, int k){
    string sum;
    string sNames;
    int sCodes = 0;

    if (k < 0)
        k = 0;

    // Base case just print all the numbers 1 at a time
    if (k == 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cout << A.at(i).getCode() << " - " << A.at(i).getName() << endl;
        return;
    }

    // current_k goes from 0 to k-1 and simulates a total of 
    // k iterations
    if (current_k < k){
        // if current_k = 0, and k = 3 (i.e. we need to find combinations of 4) 
        // then we need to leave out 3 numbers from the end because there are 3
        // more nested loops
        for (int i = start; i < n - (k - current_k); i++){
            // Store the number in the comb array and recursively call with the remaining sub-array
            comb.push_back(mcl(A.at(i).getCode(),A.at(i).getName()));
            // This will basically pass a sub array starting at index 'start' and going till n-1
            combinations(A, comb, i + 1, n, current_k + 1, k);
        }
    }

    else if (current_k == k){
        for (int i = start; i < n; i++){
            comb.at(current_k-1) = A.at(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){
                sCodes += comb.at(j).getCode();
                if (sNames != ""){
                    sNames = sNames + "," + comb.at(j).getName();
                }

                else{
                    sNames = sNames + comb.at(j).getName();
                }
            }
        }

        results.push_back(sCodes + " - " + sNames);
        sCodes = 0;
        sNames = "";
    }

    else
        return;
}

int main(){
    int k;
    vector<mcl> A,comb;

    A.push_back(mcl(1, "Light"));
    A.push_back(mcl(2, "Bright"));
    A.push_back(mcl(4, "Dark"));

    k = 2;
    

    combinations(A, comb, 0, A.size(), 0, k - 1);

    //system("cls");
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < results.size(); i1++){
        cout << results.at(i1) << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

mcl header and imp code:

```
#ifndef MCL_H
#define MCL_H

#include <string>

using std::string;

class mcl{
public:
    mcl(int code, string name);

    int getCode();
    string getName();

    void setCode(int i);
    void setName(string s);

private:
    int cCode;
    string cName;
};
#endif;
```

imp:

```
#include "mcl.h";

mcl::mcl(int code, string name){
    cCode = code;
    cName = name;
}

int mcl::getCode(){
    return cCode;
}

string mcl::getName(){
    return cName;
}

void mcl::setCode(int i){
    cCode = i;
}

void mcl::setName(string s){
    cName = s;
}
```

Now for the issue.  When I am attempting to test the display of the combinations of the three mcl objects I have defined in the code I am seeing this output:

> Bright,Dark
>
> ,Dark
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

As I am seeing each of the individual object's data showing correctly if I set k as 0:

> 1 - Light
>
> 2 - Bright
>
> 4 - Dark
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

I think this issue is being caused by the for loop that is creating the results vector for display but I am unsure of what the actual problem is.

As for an example of my expected output, given the hard coded elements in the code above this is what I am trying to get the tool to output (where bold are base settings and non-bolded are combinations):

**1 - Light**

**2 - Bright**

3 - Light,Bright
**4 - Dark**

5 - Light,Dark
6 - Bright,Dark
7 - Light,Bright,Dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have decided after a lot of research and testing that this is not going to work well for my situation and be much too costly performance-wise.  Instead I am opting for a in-database (SQLite) solution through an intermediary table that will map IDs from one table to IDs in another table in a one-to-many relationship.  Easier to code for and very lite performance wise in comparison to the brute force method of handling it all through code as the above example was attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code for a while; and trying to understand what you are after it is this section of your code found within the combinations function that have caught my attention:

```
    else if ( current_k == k ) {
        for ( int i = start; i < n; i++ ) {
            comb.at(current_k-1) = A.at(i);

            for ( int j = 0; j < k; j++ ){
                sCodes += comb.at(j).getCode();
                if ( sNames != "" ) {
                    sNames = sNames + "," + comb.at(j).getName();

                } else {
                    sNames = sNames + comb.at(j).getName();
                }
            }
        }

        results.push_back(sCodes + " - " + sNames);
        sCodes = 0;
        sNames = "";

    } else {
        return;
    }
```

What I am thinking here is you are going through a double for loop and you do not update your vector until after the double for loop finished. Is this what you want? Or do you mean to save after each iteration of the inner for loop? If So then you would just need to move this to the inside of the inner for loop after your if else statement where the modified code would look as this:

```
    else if ( current_k == k ) {
        for ( int i = start; i < n; i++ ) {
            comb.at(current_k-1) = A.at(i);

            for ( int j = 0; j < k; j++ ){
                sCodes += comb.at(j).getCode();
                if ( sNames != "" ) {
                    sNames = sNames + "," + comb.at(j).getName();

                } else {
                    sNames = sNames + comb.at(j).getName();
                }

                results.push_back(sCodes + " - " + sNames);
            }
        }

        sCodes = 0;
        sNames = "";

    } else {
        return;
    }
```

Let me know if this helps you out in any way; unfortunately I did not have the available time to try and recreate your code in my IDE to try and compile, build, run and debug to see if the output of the modified version is correct. I'm doing this visually from the top of my head. If I have some free time in the near future; I may be able to do so and try to see what I can come up with.

Comment: I tried this but it did not change much except that one additional element was added to the results vector.  What I am attempting to do is to get the output like this given the hard coded elements in the code: 1 - Light 2 - Bright 3 - Light,Bright 4 - Dark 5 - Light, Dark 6 - Bright,Dark 7 - Light,Bright,Dark

Comment: Yeah I tried reading through your code and I kind of understand what you are trying to do; but your algorithm is a tough one to tackle. Maybe in a couple of days from now; I'll have to copy your code into my IDE and work on it to see what is going on in the debugger so that I may be able to provide you with a little more insight.